# Gulp build with browserify environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, gulp, browserify

I'm looking to include either an environment variable or file that my modules can access for conditional flow.

```
// contains env build specific data
// or value 'develop' || 'production'
var env = require('config');
```

I know I can access the CL arguments with `yargs` which is great, but I can't seem to find a way to get arguments into my browserify build.

```
var bundleStream = {
  cache: {},
  packageCache: {},
  fullPaths: false,
  entries: [filename],
  extensions: config.extensions,
  debug: config.debug,
  paths: ['./node_modules', './app/js/'],
  require: ['jquery', 'lodash']
};

var bundle = function() {
  bundleLogger.start(filename);
  return bundleStream
    .bundle()
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(source(filename.replace('-app', '-bundle')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(process.cwd()))
    .on('end', reportFinished)
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a `config.json` file dynamically, and then require it in your modules:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gutil = require('gulp-utils');

gulp.task('create-config', function(cb) {
  fs.writeFile('config.json', JSON.stringify({
    env: gutil.env.env,
    tacos: 'delicious'
  }), cb);
});

gulp.task('browserify', ['create-config'], function() {
  //...
});
```

In your modules:

```
var config = require('./config.json');
if (config.env === 'production') {
  //...
}
```

And on the command line:

```
gulp --env=production
```